# Typescript equivalent of decltype in C++?

Tags: typescript

`decltype` in C++ returns the type of an expression, for example `decltype(1+1)` will be `int`.

Note that the expression won't be executed or compiled.

Does Typescript has something similar?

Example usecase that i think should work:

```
const foo = () => ({a: '', b: 0});
type foo_return_type = decltype(foo());
// foo_return_type should be '{a: stirng, b: number}`

import { bar } from './some_module';
type my_type = decltype(new bar().some_method());
```

Comment: The closest is `typeof` in type position but it's only for variables, not expressions. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606

Comment: I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297361/create-type-for-un-exported-typescript-parameter) (before finding yours), looks like no luck :(

Comment: I was googling for "typescript computed interface",  "typecript infered return type interface", and the like with no luck until I remembered the c++ equivalent. [Maybe this comment helps SEO?]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ReturnType` for this ([introduced in typescript 2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types))

```
function foo() {
    return {a: '', b: 0}
}

class bar {
    some_method() {
        return {x: '', z: 0}
    }
}

type fooReturnType = ReturnType<typeof foo>
/**

    type fooReturnType = {
        a: string;
        b: number;
    }

*/

type barReturnType = ReturnType<typeof bar.prototype.some_method>
/**

    type barReturnType = {
        x: string;
        z: number;
    }

*/
```

Comment: You can also use `Parameters` to get the type of the parameters of a function. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to get the type of a field on a type, and the key lookup worked for me `Class['field']` instead of `Class.field`.

Not sure why, but it does!

```
type Foo = {
    bar: (b: number) => void;
}

type BrokenBar = Foo.bar; //doesn't work
type Bar = Foo['bar']; //does compile
```

[Demo here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUBGBDAJwC4oAKHEgOwFcBbHCAgSmQD4oA3OASwBMBudAF906APRjQkKACECcANYRKMwslgIAdPgL8oE3nAgBnSgHJgUAO5wCC9FOiqC6%20HADaZnWYC6eg0bGUADGcLRg3AA20KKhlMZw0ZqRcADmpABEACJwlBAAhBlMQA)