# Create type for un-exported typescript parameter

Tags: typescript, types

We're using a module that does't export the type of all its parameters. This means that the arguments are typechecked but we can't define a variable of the required type before the method call.

**Example:**

```
//  library
interface Internal { foo(): number } // I want to have a name for this un-exported interface

class A {
    bar(s: string, x: Internal): string {
        return s + x.foo(); // whatever
    }
}
export const Exported = A;
```

When using `Exported.bar` is there a way for me to first define the argument so that it's correctly typed?

```
let e = new Exported();
let x : /*???*/;
e.bar("any ideas?", x);
```

I thought of a way to use generics to create a `null` of type `Internal` so I can give `x` the correct type but this is very clunky, is there a way to capture this type in a `type` definition and use it more cleanly?

```
function deduce<T>(f: (s: string, t: T) => any): T {
    return null;
}
let x = deduce(e.bar);
```

Comment: Do you want the interface name during development time? A simple right click + "Go to definition" (or F12 in VS Code) on the method call will do the trick...

Comment: @LajosGallay I know the name (I can see it in the `.d.ts`) but it's not exported so I can't use it in code. I could copy/paste it but then if the library changed I wouldn't get the changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get argument types from function in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51851677/how-to-get-argument-types-from-function-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Type Inference with conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) is a solution for you:

In the case of your sample code:

```
let e = new Exported();
// Type Inference Practice:
type ARG<T> = T extends ((a: any, b: infer U) => void) ? U : T;
type B = ARG<typeof e["bar"]>;

let x : B;  // <-- let x : /*???*/;
e.bar("any ideas?", x);
```

Comment: Is there any way to define `type B` as a one-liner? Or is the temporary `ARG` type unavoidable?