# Parameters type of a generic function with specific generic type argument, in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Consider this code in a third party package:

```
// A third-party package
type InternalComplexType<T> = ...; // not exported
export function foo<T>(arg1: T, arg2: InternalComplexType<T>): void {}
```

How can I get `InternalComplexType<number>` for example?

This fails:

```
type SecondArgType = Parameters<typeof foo<number>>[1]; // syntax error
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEENQFwCwSwE4BMC0AHcCoE9QYMYDW4A5gKYBQOaZoAkgHZRkIPgA2AwgPYC2a7MgA8AKthoAeEQD5QAXlAjQAH1AMArrwBGLANygQa7lFDC03LGSQUzFkwDN1DfFDjcGoe925TpACkwSAEYALkUAGggEEgAmMMZmVg4efkFRcTJfAEowgDduOCRQAG8AXwoKQxhuAHdoblByEwSWNi4+AWExSQ1tFmkAfioM0ABlMnx3JABBaO7aBQAFTHBeMkSAZwlqMm57T28JXp0EaWkAbSCAXX1DWDgNz3A4dg2gA)

Answer (score 0):

So the best way to achieve this is changing the function definition by an interface function definition, such that it works with typescript utility types. Doing `typeof func` and trying to pass the generic within the `typeof` wont work at the moment with typescript compiler. Thus the error.

You can do it like this:

```
type InternalComplexType<T> = T | number;
export function foo<T>(arg1: T, arg2: InternalComplexType<T>): void {}

// create an interface type for you generic function
interface foo<T>{
   (arg1: T, arg2: InternalComplexType<T>): T
}

type SecondArgType = Parameters<foo<number>>[1];
```

Comment: The problem in the first place is that `InternalComplexType` is not exported from the third-party package. If I had access to `InternalComplexType<T>`, I wouldn't even face this problem.

Comment: @AlirezaMirian I don't understand. You would have faced the syntax error even if that type was exported. The above solution will definitely solve your syntax error. Regarding accessing the exported type, please refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/54309851/8523669 .

Comment: I see, and thank you for your time. The point is that I'm looking for a way to use type `InternalComplexType<number>`, which happens to require getting `Parameters` of a generic function based on an specific generic argument value. So a solution that assumes I have access to `InternalComplexType` is pointless. I thought I made it clear by naming it **Internal**ComplexType and adding a "not exported" comment :)